# What coin/token is this? Copper "1 1900" Rev: Austro-Hungarian arms

Tags: identification, numismatics

I am unable to locate any information regarding this coin/token. Can anyone help?!!

[image: Coin]

Comment: A picture of the face (in addition to the obverse shown) would help.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be from Austria, the Austro-Hungarian Empire, and is a [one Heller coin](https://www.vcoins.com/en/stores/cyber_coins__banknotes/43/product/austria_austrohungarian_empire_franz_joseph_i_1900_1_heller__extra_fine/842249/Default.aspx).

[image]

Comment: A One Heller What coin? ;-) 
Sorry; I couldn't hep myself.

Comment: Nice work, how did you find that based just on the one motif?

Comment: Mostly luck, I think the final search hit was on terms  1900 copper coin.